# Why are websockets favored over HTTP streams when sending notifications to clients?

Tags: api, rest, websocket

I have a REST backend ( using Go ) and want to send notifications to the clients whenever something happened on the server side.

**I don't want to cover message brokers here, I know they exist.** Most people seem to solve this by using websockets. But you could also have an additional API endpoint to stream data ( e.g. notifications ) via `application/x-ndjson` ( of course clients will have to parse the streamed data ).

I would like to know why most people seem to favor websockets over HTTP streaming.

- Because it's faster? ( [How websockets can be faster than a simple HTTP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169427/how-websockets-can-be-faster-than-a-simple-http-request) )
- Because it's easier to implement? ( you don't have to parse a streamed json string )

I think introducting a second "protocol" of communication comes with new problems, right? So why not just stick with HTTP streaming?